# How can I limit frame count by counting a text list?

Tags: python, scripting, animation-nodes, drivers

I have a list of names in a Text Block that are separated by line. There will be different amounts of names. I am using the list to generate titles but want to render one title per frame. I want to render each frame using the current name from the list.
So I need to :

1. Read the list for number of lines
2. Change the scene length to total number of lines
3. Copy and Enter the current name in the "file output" field
4. Render frame

I am using Animation Nodes to generate the changing text, perhaps I can get number of lines from Text Block List Length?
Also I could get the current "Name" from Split Text reader to enter in the File Output?

[image: title AN output values]

Can I send Values (frame total) and Strings (file names) from Animation Nodes to Blender?

Answer (score 1):

You may use an *Expression* node. The two properties you want to edit a scene properties. You can know their path from their python tool-tip (Hover over the property). So the expression node can be as follows:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: I thought about using an Expression node but doesn't it remain inside Animation Nodes? Will it be expressed in Blender itself? Hmmm Thanks I'll try it tomorrow ;-) Also I really appreciate your help Omar

Comment: @3pointedit You can edit anything in blender from an expression/script node. Except maybe the current context.

Comment: I just learned that to include the preferred path as a string I need to double the \ character ;-) so it's "C:\\Folder"